# Flutter TextField with maxLength and

Tags: flutter, textfield, maxlength

I need a Text Area with an enforced maxLength of 250 chars and its label aligned with the hint text. My code is below.

However, the widget is rendering the text on top of the hint. Does anyone know a solution? 
It's like if the counter widget forces the actual text field to move upwards.

[TextField with maxLength = 250 and alignLabelWithHint = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQWQC.jpg)

```
TextField(
    expands: false,
    minLines: null,
    maxLines: null,
    maxLengthEnforced: maxLengthEnforced,
    maxLength: maxLength,
    controller: controller,
    onChanged: (String value){
      print(value);
    },
    cursorColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    keyboardType: keyboardType,
    decoration: InputDecoration(

        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        labelText: text,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        hintText: text,
        prefixIcon: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a hint is to disappear when the user start typing I tried your code and it worked with no problem.

```
TextField(
                  expands: false,
                  minLines: null,
                  maxLines: null,
                  maxLengthEnforced: true,
                  maxLength: 250,
                  // controller: controller,
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    print(value);
                  },
                  cursorColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                  // keyboardType: keyboardType,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      alignLabelWithHint: true,
                      labelText: "hi",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      hintText: "hi",
                      prefixIcon: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                              child: Material(
                                elevation: 0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.highlight,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5)),
                ),
```